# Display navigation on all but main page using sections?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How would I display a top level navigation on all pages except for the main page? I am defining the navigation inside of `Layout.cshtml`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use javascript to hide it.  When the page renders all of its html will be merged with any inherited html, so you should be able to wrap the navigation in a `<div id="nav">` and hide it with a simple jQuery function:

```
$('#nav').hide;
```